# How to display Table and Image using inline-block in Html?

Tags: html, css, layout

How can I display my image and the table on the same level? This is really depressing me because I can't get "inline-block" to work. :(

```
<p id="play">
    hey
</p>
<div id="menu">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Models</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cars</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Modern Houses</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vacation Spots</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sports and Outdoors</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Books</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Abandoned Houses</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Summer Wear</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Makeups</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="site">Site Info</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<img src="C:\Users\Elexie\Documents\Downloads\faki2.jpg"/>


body {
    background: #181818;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* set body display to inline-table*/
#play {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 35px;
}

table,td {
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: ;
}

table {

}

#site {
    height: 350px;
}

img {
    float: right;
}
```

I changed the picture, but it's of similar size
http://jsfiddle.net/w6d5g/

Answer (score 0):

In your css code:

```
table{
float:left;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Read more: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: If you want the picture to be next to the table, instead of floating on the right side of the screen, change the float of the img to left `img { float:left;}`

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mohamed_nabil/F8MKp/

```
/*******Added style******/
img
{
    /*165px is your Menu width with borders*/
    max-width: calc(100% - 165px);
    /*For cross browser*/
    -webkit-max-width: calc(100% - 165px);
    -moz-max-width: calc(100% - 165px);
    -o-max-width: calc(100% - 165px);
    -ms-max-width: calc(100% - 165px);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;/* Can be middle, bottom */
}
#menu{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, wrap your image tag with a div. Name this div anything you want. Let's name it: "image-test".

```
<div class="image-test">
  <img src="(URL for IMAGE)">
</div>
```

Next, let's say you want your table to take up 50% of the width and your image to take up the other 50%. We are also going to float these div elements so they are not in the flow of the document.

```
#menu{
  float:left;
  width:50%;

}
.image-test{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

You'll notice your image is larger than the containing div, so let's set a max width on all images to avoid future problems.

```
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```